# Swift dictionary all containing

Tags: swift, dictionary

Lets say I have dictionaries like below and wanted an array of red dogs. I figured I need to get an array of all the names of the type "dog" using the first dictionary, and then use the name key and the color to search the final dictionary to get ["Polly,"jake"]. I've tried using loops but can't figure out how to iterate through the dictionary.

```
var pets = ["Polly" : "dog", "Joey" : "goldfish", "Alex" : "goldfish", "jake" : "dog"]

var petcolor = ["Polly" : "red", "Joey" : "black", "Alex" : "yellow", "jake":red"]
```

Comment: Might be a better idea to use objects than dictionaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct solution would seem to be to create a `Pet` struct (or class) and collate all of this information into a struct and build either an array or dictionary full of these values.

```
struct Pet {
    let name: String
    let type: String
    let color: String

    init(name: String, type: String, color: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.type = type
        self.color = color
    }
}
```

Now, let's build an array of these pets:

```
var goodPets = [Pet]()

for (petName, petType) in pets {
    guard let petColor = petcolor[petName] else {
        // Found this pet's type, but couldn't find its color. Can't add it.
        continue
    }

    goodPets.append(Pet(name: petName, type: petType, color: petColor))
}
```

Now that we've filled out `goodPets`, pulling out any particular subset of Pets becomes *very* easy:

```
let redDogs = goodPets.filter { $0.type == "dog" && $0.color = "red" }
```

And although this answer looks like a lot of set up & legwork compared to other answers, the major advantage here is that once we build the `goodPets` array, ***any*** way we want to scoop pets out of there ends up being more efficient.  And as we increase the number of properties the pets have, this becomes more and more true compared to the other answers.

---

If you'd rather store our model objects in a dictionary continuing to use the names as the keys, we can do that as well, but the filter looks a little bit stranger.

Building the dictionary looks *mostly* the same:

```
var goodPets = [String : Pet]()

for (petName, petType) in pets {
    guard let petColor = petcolor[petName] else {
        // Found this pet's type, but couldn't find its color. Can't add it.
        continue
    }

    goodPets[petName] = (Pet(name: petName, type: petType, color: petColor))
}
```

But the filter is slightly different:

```
let redDogs = goodPets.filter { $0.1.type = "dog" && $0.1.color = "red" }
```

Note that in both cases, `redDogs` has the type `[Pet]`, that is, an array of `Pet` values.

Comment: Im going to use this as I plan on adding criteria. Lets say A user enters a type, and not a color: Is there any way to ignore the lack of color criteria and give all the dogs without a bunch of if statements?

Comment: @user3015221 Your best from this point is to implement something *that works*, and then head on down to [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) to get it cleaned up.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through a dictionary like this:

```
for key in pets.keys() {
    if pets[key] == "Dog" {

    }
}
```

Or:

```
for (name, pet) in pets {
    if pet == "Dog" {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

nhgrif is probably correct about structure but, to answer the literal question:

```
let dogs = Set(pets.filter { $0.1 == "dog" }.map { $0.0 })
let redAnimals = Set(petscolor.filter { $0.1 == "red" }.map { $0.0 })

let redDogs = dogs.intersect(redAnimals)
```

Each `filter` is a block that operates on a (key, value) tuple, testing the value and ultimately creating a dictionary with only the matching (key, value) pairs. Each `map` then converts that filtered dictionary into an array by discarding the values and just keeping the keys.

Each array is turned into a set to support the `intersect` operation. The `intersect` then determines the intersection of the two results.